# NLog not always logging as the right class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nlog

I started development on an **ASP .NET MVC** project, running on *.NET 4.8.1*.

I wanted to use NLog for logging and decided to add it through DI.

Not being used to doing this in ASP .NET, I googled and found a "how to" using **Unity**.

I started by adding the necessary references:

[image: Reference 1]
[image: Reference 2]

Added a file **UnitConfig.cs** in **App_Start**:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Unity;
using Unity.Mvc5;
using Unity.NLog;

namespace SomeSite
{
    public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.AddNewExtension<NLogExtension>();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        }
    }
}
```

Added a reference in **Global.asax.cs**:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace SomeSite
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
        }
    }
}
```

And then I added a constructor & a log line in each of my 2 Controllers, like this:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using NLog;

namespace SomeSite.Controllers
{
    public class SomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        #region Constructors
        public SomeController (ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        #endregion

        // GET: Some
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.Trace("SomeController - Index");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

For good measure, I added a simple "Hello World" view, and @ first sight everything works, I get a log file, and each of the controllers logs it:

```
2024-01-28 18:51:51.3988 TRACE SomeSite.Controllers.SomeController SomeController - Index 
2024-01-28 18:51:59.8301 TRACE SomeSite.Controllers.SomeController SomeController1 - Index
```

But as you can see, each of the log lines indicates it originates from the same class/controller **SomeSite.Controllers.SomeController**, while in reality the 2nd line should have been written as originating from **SomeSite.Controllers.SomeController1**.

So my question then becomes: what causes this and how can I fix it?

Perhaps a configuration issue? This is my **nlog.xml**:

```
<nlog
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
  <targets>
    <target
      name="coloredConsole"
      xsi:type="ColoredConsole"
      useDefaultRowHighlightingRules="false"
      layout="${longdate}|${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}|${message}"
    >
      <highlight-row
        condition="level == LogLevel.Debug"
        foregroundColor="DarkGray"
      />
      <highlight-row
        condition="level == LogLevel.Info"
        foregroundColor="Gray"
      />
      <highlight-row
        condition="level == LogLevel.Warn"
        foregroundColor="Yellow"
      />
      <highlight-row
        condition="level == LogLevel.Error"
        foregroundColor="Red"
      />
      <highlight-row
        condition="level == LogLevel.Fatal"
        foregroundColor="Red"
        backgroundColor="White"
      />
    </target>

    <target
      name="traceFile"
      xsi:type="File"
      layout="${longdate} ${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}} ${logger} ${message}"
      fileName="d:/Debug/MyClient/SomeSite/Logging/Trace_${shortdate}.log"
      keepFileOpen="false"
      encoding="iso-8859-2"
    />
    <target
      name="errorFile"
      xsi:type="File"
      layout="${longdate} ${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}} ${logger} ${message}"
      fileName="d:/Debug/MyClient/SomeSite/Logging/Error_${shortdate}.log"
      keepFileOpen="false"
      encoding="iso-8859-2"
    />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="coloredConsole" />

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="traceFile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" maxlevel="Fatal" writeTo="errorFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Looks to complicated, just add a global static Log

Comment: Which is an approach I prefer to avoid...

Comment: Ok can you double check the logic, where is the code that prints this line: Index 2024-01-29 11:51:32.2460 TRACE SomeSite.Controllers.SomeController SomeController1 - Index?

Comment: You wrote SomeSite.Controllers.SomeController while the log is SomeSite.Controllers.AirGatewayController

Comment: Yes, an error when I posted tghe log file. :-) Fixed it.

Comment: The code used to log the second line is in a seperate controller, identical to the one I've shown here. The only difference is the name of the controller, and of course it logs SomeController1-Index.